# wp7 app tile effect

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, tile, live-tile

i am creating a windows phone application with tile effects, but somewhere i confused using/creating tiles. i just confused between application & secondary tile, what's the difference between?

Actually my requirements is to create a page within my app, which contains some tiles (i am saying these as tiles, might be these are something else). the pictures are shown below to make more clear--->[image]

whenever the user clicks on any of these tiles, he would redirect to the corresponding page. (to  some page), for example:- if he clicks on message tile, then he will redirect to the some page showing messages.

i also wants to ask that if these are not tiles, then wat are these looking like tiles & containing some regular updating text ???
& what is difference between application tiles & secondary tiles ?

note:- the image is of some wp7 app, which is edited to make clear about my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For navigation between pages use the NavigationService.Navigate method.

There are no controls behaving in the same way as tiles, so you are required to implement the functionality you need. You can use a clever cobination of Rectangle, transparent-background images and text blocks, which together could respond to tap event and navigate.